# Will (Minor) Push upgrades conflict with running batches?

Tags: apex, batch, scheduled-apex, isv, push-upgrade

What will happing to running Apex Batch jobs when I perform a Push (Minor) Upgrade (Patch) into a customer org?

Is that save to do? Under which circumstances?
I could not find documentation or any other experience reports related to this issue.

Comment: I am also curious about this. You should be able to test on your own though.

Comment: is this even allowed to run push upgrade to minor or major version?